# question with the initialisation of my constructor (begginer question)

Tags: c++, class, constructor, operator-overloading, copy-constructor

for my assignment i had to do a Rational class and add the operators.
and if the input for the denominator is 1 or the numerator is 0, output need to be just the numerator. So i wanted to initialize my copy constructor but i didn't really success (you can see i put it in comments) or maybe i need to change my print function? So if you could help me..
thank u

```
//Rational.h
#ifndef Rational_h
#define Rational_h

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Rational{
public:
    //default cstr
    Rational(int myNumerator=1, int myDenominator=1):numerator(myNumerator),denominator(myDenominator){}
    //copy cstr
    Rational (Rational const &num):numerator(num.getNumerator()),denominator(num.getDenominator()){
        /*if (denominator==1 or numerator==0) {
           // num=numerator;
        }*/
    }
    void setNumerator(int);
    void setDenominator(int);
    int getNumerator()const;
    int getDenominator()const;
    void print();
    void reduction(int,int);
    Rational operator/(Rational);

private:
    int numerator;
    int denominator;

};

#endif /* Rational_h */


//  Rational.cpp

void Rational::setNumerator(int myNumerator){
    numerator=myNumerator;
}
void Rational::setDenominator(int myDenominator){

    if (myDenominator==0){
        cout<<"ERROR"<<endl;
        denominator=1;
        }
    else
        denominator=myDenominator;
}

int Rational::getNumerator()const{
    return numerator;
}
void Rational::print(){
    cout<<numerator<<"/"<<denominator<<endl;
}

void Rational::reduction(int numerator,int denominator)
{
  for (int i = denominator * numerator; i > 1; i--)
     if ((denominator % i == 0) && (numerator % i == 0)) {
         denominator /= i;
         numerator /= i;
        }
}

Rational Rational::operator/(Rational num){
    Rational newNum;
    newNum.numerator=numerator*num.denominator;
    newNum.denominator=denominator*num.numerator;
    newNum.reduction(newNum.numerator, newNum.denominator);
    return newNum;
}
```

Comment: This is what you need to do: print out the above on a sheet of paper. Take a 2nd sheet of paper, and cut out just the part that lets "`num=numerator`" part visible. Cover it, so this is only thing that you see, any more. Now, take a third sheet of paper and write down a very detailed explanation of what this statement does, and what it's expected to accomplish. Make your explanation as detailed as possible, cover every possible meaning and nuance. Now, remove the 2nd sheet of paper, exposing the entire class and the constructor, reread what you wrote and see if it makes sense any more.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write your own copy constructor here at all. The auto-generated copy constructor will do what you want. It will either be generated if you do nothing at all, or more clearly if you explicitly ask for it with:

```
Rational (const  Rational& num)=default;
```

You only normally need to write your own copy constructor if you class contains pointers, which this one doesn't.

As to your logic regarding denominators and numerators, it doesn't belong in the copy constructor. Any rules you have apply to all objects, not just copied ones, and so it should be in the other constructor. One the original object has the correct values, then any copy must also be correct.